# Has the concept of allostasis been adopted in biology, in place of homeostasis?

Tags: physiology, brain, homeostasis

[Peter Sterling](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=peter+sterling+allostasis&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C22), among others, has been a prominent critic of the concept of homeostasis.  He instead proposes a process called [allostasis](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031938411003076).

**Homeostasis** involves having fixed set points for physiological parameters, and when we deviate from those set points, there are mechanisms that restore them.

However, Sterling argues that this process of homeostasis is inefficient and inflexible.  Instead, he posits that the brain is constantly predicting physiological needs based on environmental and bodily demands, such that the "set point" changes depending on the context.  So your mean blood pressure might be X in one context, but Y in another.  And rather than responding after a deviation from the mean, the brain predicts those deviations and adjusts the body accordingly.  This is **allostasis**.

[image]

Allostasis is much more in line with what we know about the brain (e.g., [Clark, 2013](http://users.monash.edu/~naotsugt/Tsuchiya_Labs_Homepage/Bryan_Paton_files/Commentary%20.pdf)), but has this idea been adopted much in biology?  Based on my memory from biology class not long ago, it seems like homeostasis is still considered a central feature of living things.

Thanks!

Comment: For those that don't have a subscription to that particular journal, can you find or post a copy in some easily and permanently-accessible place? Or, at the very least, highlight his arguments for it and provide links to supporting evidence? Sometimes ideas like this are just too new to have gotten much traction yet, other times they're crackpot hypotheses that don't fit with existing data. Sure, it *sounds* nice, but where's the evidence?

Comment: @MattDMo  [Here's a freely available article](http://retina.anatomy.upenn.edu/pdfiles/6277.pdf) of his from 2004 and you can download a more recent article from researchgate [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51229788_Allostasis_A_Model_of_Predictive_Regulation).

Comment: Thanks. By the way, just to be clear, I have no opinion at all as to whether this is an accepted hypothesis or not, as this isn't my field of study. But I have been involved in other similar questions asking "Why isn't this theory of Professor XYZ more accepted in the community?" and it turns out that XYZ is a crackpot conspiracy theorist who is chief editor and publisher of his own journal and organization that espouses the garbage he writes about, regardless of any possible "merit" or "scientific evidence". I'll try to link you to the question if I can, I don't remember it at the moment.

Comment: @MattDMo  I definitely understand the concern.  Although Peter Sterling is a reputable academic, and a prominent physiologist I work with seems to find strong validity in his theory.  But who knows!

Comment: Eh, personal views here as a biologist, so I'll keep this in a comment rather than an answer: Everything in biology comes with huge asterisks and exceptions. This is often a point of confusion for novices and non-biologists, but to me it's just a way of thinking when you deal with life. I think it's pretty clear from your diagram that a major component of "allostasis" is indeed homeostasis: it's homeostasis with a little bit of predictive power. Outside of biology, in control theory, this is a pretty basic part of set point regulation: when you want to keep something at a set point, maybe...

Comment: ...temperature, you don't just think about your current temperature but you look at rate of change, etc, to make some future predictions. So, is homeostasis everything? No of course not. You can maybe get some publicity if you say "Hey everyone! Homeostasis isn't everything!" But of course that's obviously true: organisms grow, they reproduce, they grow old and die. You might start releasing energy stores when you wake up in the morning rather than when you start jogging. Homeostasis is still a pretty powerful descriptor in most cases, a lot like Newtonian physics on Earth.

Comment: I don't know Peter Sterling. Maybe he is just trying to get attention. Maybe he just wants to emphasize the exceptions to the rule. From your description it sounds a lot like a physicist who goes around the party telling everyone F=ma is wrong. Everyone knows he is right, but he isn't really convincing them of anything they don't already know, and they think he's annoying anyways.

Comment: @BryanKrause  I suppose I'm a bit confused by your last paragraph.  Peter Sterling is a legitimate, well-respected academic.  He's not trying to get attention.  If you read his articles, they're well reasoned and well evidenced.  Did my language somehow paint him as a crackpot?  (Sincere question.)

Comment: @BryanKrause  Also, Peter Sterling isn't claiming that "homeostasis isn't everything."  He's saying that such a process isn't functional without prior knowledge and predictions.  This is very, very important in areas like (human and non-human) neuroscience and psychology (where it's routinely ignored and so theory suffers), so I'd imagine it's also very important in biology.

Comment: I'm saying that what he calls allostasis doesn't sound any different from what most biologists would understand homeostasis to include. It seems from your description that he is setting up a straw man for homeostasis. The key flags for me in your question were "instead of" and describing him as a "critic" of homeostasis. No experienced biologist would claim that homeostasis means set points can't change - that's silly, hence why it is a straw man argument.

Comment: That said there may be nothing wrong with his work, he may just be stressing an issue he feels is overlooked or not treated explicitly by others. Maybe your characterization of his work is a bit exaggerated? Or maybe he exaggerates himself - it's not a bad rhetorical technique, I think you are just taking it to far with the idea that somehow other biologists aren't accepting that set points change or organisms make predictions on future needs.

Comment: @BryanKrause   Got it, thanks!   Although, to be fair, if you look at the history of the concept homeostasis, it has a very specific meaning, so I'm not entirely sure it's a straw man.

Comment: @mrt I looked at the Wikipedia page for allostasis, a quote: ["Allostasis is the process of achieving stability, or homeostasis, through physiological or behavioral change"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allostasis).

I could define a new term myself, "Ezzting: the process of achieving nutritional intake, or eating, by putting food items in your mouth and chewing them." Do you think that term will take the world by storm and replace the clearly inferior verb "to eat"?

Comment: I don't think "allostasis" is as much a farce as my example, but it will not replace homeostasis because the definition of "allostasis" is already the definition most biologists would use for "homeostasis" - no one except the people behind "allostasis" seem to be defining homeostasis so narrowly as to need a secondary term. I came to this conclusion independently, but it looks like I am not alone, as the Wikipedia article on allostasis also led me to this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S027858460500268X) which seems to share my take.

Comment: @BryanKrause  I think if you read the two papers I linked from Sterling, it would clear up a lot of confusion.  Wikipedia isn't really a great source here.  I can't keep defending something if you're not familiar with it.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score -1):

Allostasis is more than changing set points. The theory of allostasis attempts to unify the theories of stress and homeostasis. And, although Peter Sterling and Joseph Eyer were the first to coin the term "allostasis", the concept is today proposed by a plethora of researchers.

Allostatic responses ensure „stability through change“ in situations of strain and stress. If in allostatic mode a feedback control system is able to change both its set point and its parameters to approach a state vector that is more suitable for survival. An allostatic response involves the activation of actuator variables that is referred to as allostatic state. Although allostasis is basically beneficial for viability it also exposes the organism to some kind of strain, referred to as allostatic load. If ongoing or being excessive, allostatic load may be life-threatening on its own terms. In this situation, it is referred to as allostatic overload.

[image]
Figure taken from [Chatzitomaris et al. 2017](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fendo.2017.00163/full).

The idea of allostasis might have been omitted in your biology class due to didactical reasons. For an introductory course it may be beneficial to begin with the simpler theory of homeostasis.

Today, the concept of allostasis is of increasing importance for psychology and medicine. As of today, a PubMed search for the term "allostasis" results in 730 papers and a search for "allostatic load" delivers 1123 publications (with growing tendency).

The theory of allostasis helped to improve our understanding of a broad range of diseases and non-pathological bio-psycho-social situations. Typical examples include starvation, obesity, exercise, fever, type 2 diabetes, hypertension, thyroid disorders, post-traumatic stress disorder (PTSD) and psychosomatic diseases. Additionally, the recent development of panels for allostatic load facilitates differential diagnosis near the small ridge between health and disease.

**References**

1. Sterling P, Eyer J. Biological basis of stress-related mortality. Soc Sci Med E. 1981 Feb;15(1):3-42. PMID [7020084](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7020084).
2. Sterling P. [Allostasis: a model of predictive regulation](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031938411003076?via%3Dihub). Physiol Behav. 2012 Apr 12;106(1):5-15. doi: 10.1016/j.physbeh.2011.06.004. Epub 2011 Jun 12. PMID [21684297](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21684297).
3. Bizik G, Picard M, Nijjar R, Tourjman V, McEwen BS, Lupien SJ, Juster RP. Allostatic load as a tool for monitoring physiological dysregulations and comorbidities in patients with severe mental illnesses. Harv Rev Psychiatry. 2013 Nov-Dec;21(6):296-313. doi: 10.1097/HRP.0000000000000012. PMID [24201821](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24201821).
4. Sagner M, McNeil A, Puska P, Auffray C, Price ND, Hood L, Lavie CJ, Han ZG, Chen Z, Brahmachari SK, McEwen BS, Soares MB, Balling R, Epel E, Arena R. [The P4 Health Spectrum - A Predictive, Preventive, Personalized and Participatory Continuum for Promoting Healthspan](http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0033-0620(16)30078-0). Prog Cardiovasc Dis. 2017 Mar - Apr;59(5):506-521. doi: 10.1016/j.pcad.2016.08.002. PMID [27546358](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27546358).
5. Chatzitomaris A, Hoermann R, Midgley JE, Hering S, Urban A, Dietrich B, Abood A, Klein HH, Dietrich JW. [Thyroid Allostasis-Adaptive Responses of Thyrotropic Feedback Control to Conditions of Strain, Stress, and Developmental Programming](http://dx.doi.org/10.3389/fendo.2017.00163). Front Endocrinol (Lausanne). 2017 Jul 20;8:163. doi: 10.3389/fendo.2017.00163. PMID [28775711](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28775711).